# UITableView allow swipe to delete but not longpress

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have both swipe left to delete gesture and longpress (to switch cells).

When there is only 1 cell, I want only the delete to be enabled but not the long press.

They are both handled by:
`-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

If I return `YES` in it - both swipe and long press will be available. I want only swipe in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the number of rows by this:

```
   - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSInteger count = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];

        if (count == 1) {       
               for (UIGestureRecognizer * gesture in cell.gestureRecognizers) {
                   if ([gesture isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]]) {
                      [cell removeGestureRecognizer:gesture];
                   }
               }
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"do something else");
        }

        return YES;
     }
```

and then accordingly proceed.

Comment: I think I was misunderstood. I know how to figure out there is only 1, but if I return YES - both swipe and longpress will work. I want only swipe to work

Comment: edited the original question so (hopefully) it's clearer

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
[TableView numberOfRowsInSection:yourSection];
```

the above method in your delegate

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

& then you can implement checks & perform your task accordingly.

Comment: I think I was misunderstood. I know how to figure out there is only 1, but if I return YES - both swipe and longpress will work. I want only swipe to work

Comment: edited the original question so (hopefully) it's clearer